# xamarin load data into label from list

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin

I have 2 labels 'firstName' and 'lastName' that if i click on button 'pushNext'
it will do the insert function that insert the data to list

```
partial void pushNext_TouchUpInside (UIButton sender)
{
    Core.insert(firstName.Text,lastName.Text);
}
```

in the class Core

```
public class Core
{
    public static List<string> values = new List<string>();
    public Core ()
    {
    }
    public static void insert(string first,string last){
        Core.values.Add (first);
        Core.values.Add (last);

    }
```

the click button past me to the next view be push

```
partial class nextView : UIViewController
{
    public nextView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
    {
        lastLabel.Text = Core.getdata ();
    }
}
```

and in this view I'm trying to get the data from the Core class

```
public static string getdata(){

    return Core.values[0] ;


}
```

in this point I can see that the Core.values[0] have the right value
but in this point i got an error
System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.Exception: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
  at DsignerWalkthroug.nextView..ctor (IntPtr handle) [0x00013] in /Users/shaharnakash/Projects/DsignerWalkthroug/DsignerWalkthroug/nextView.cs:12
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Reflection.MonoCMethod:InternalInvoke (System.Reflection.MonoCMethod,object,object[],System.Exception&)
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00002] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:537
  --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.InternalInvoke (System.Object obj, System.Object[] parameters) [0x00016] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:543
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.DoInvoke (System.Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00095] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:528
  at System.Reflection.MonoCMethod.Invoke (BindingFlags invokeAttr, System.Reflection.Binder binder, System.Object[] parameters, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/MonoMethod.cs:556
  at System.Reflection.ConstructorInfo.Invoke (System.Object[] parameters) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Reflection/ConstructorInfo.cs:62
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject[NSObject] (IntPtr ptr, System.Type type, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x0003e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:427
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.ConstructNSObject (IntPtr ptr, IntPtr klass, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00013] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:408
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetNSObject (IntPtr ptr, MissingCtorResolution missingCtorResolution) [0x00021] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:492
  at MonoTouch.Registrar.DynamicRegistrar.GetMethodDescriptionAndObject (System.Type type, IntPtr selector, IntPtr obj, Boolean throw_on_failure, System.IntPtr& mthis) [0x0003e] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/DynamicRegistrar.cs:587
  at MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime.GetMethodAndObject (IntPtr klass, IntPtr sel, IntPtr obj, Boolean throw_on_failure, System.IntPtr& mthis) [0x00000] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/ObjCRuntime/Runtime.cs:242
  at at (wrapper native-to-managed) MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Runtime:GetMethodAndObject (intptr,intptr,intptr,int,intptr&)
  at at (wrapper managed-to-native) MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication:UIApplicationMain (int,string[],intptr,intptr)
  at MonoTouch.UIKit.UIApplication.Main (System.String[] args, System.String principalClassName, System.String delegateClassName) [0x0004c] in /Developer/MonoTouch/Source/monotouch/src/UIKit/UIApplication.cs:38
  at DsignerWalkthroug.Application.Main (System.String[] args) [0x00008] in /Users/shaharnakash/Projects/DsignerWalkthroug/DsignerWalkthroug/Main.cs:17

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My guess is that the label object hasn't been instantiated yet.
You should be performing initialization in ViewDidLoad() instead.

Refer to this for more info: http://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/ios_code_only/

EDIT:

Basically, your code should like like this:

```
partial class nextView : UIViewController
{
        public nextView (IntPtr handle) : base (handle)
        {
        }

        public override void ViewDidLoad()
        {
            base.ViewDidLoad();

            //perform initialization here
            lastLabel.Text = Core.getdata ();
        }
}
```

Comment: ho , thank you very much, i did not fully understand the logic , but now i understand that i need to override the xcode functions.